# R connection to Hive protobuf class error

Tags: r, hive, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to connect to a remote Hive using R, each step forward I find a new error. At the moment I'm doing that:

```
library("DBI")
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

cp = c("/path/jars/hadoop-common-3.1.0.jar", 
       "/path/jars/hive-jdbc-2.3.3-standalone.jar")
.jinit(classpath=cp)

       drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", 
"/path/jars/hive-jdbc-2.3.3-standalone.jar", 
                    identifier.quote="`")
        conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://<ip>:10000/default", "myuser", "")
```

And all I get is the following error, it's something about protobuf, but no idea it's a local problem (env?) or is it server-side.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ProtocolMessageEnum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading or getting the protobuf.jar from hadoop installation and adding it solved the problem.

```
cp = c("/path/jars/hadoop-common-3.1.0.jar", 
       "/path/jars/hive-jdbc-2.3.3-standalone.jar",
       "/path/jars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar")
```